# Discord.js V13: How to edit Message Object of Interaction?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I am trying to update my discord bot to the new version of discord.js (v13). I have a message with an embed and two buttons, one for previous Page and one for next page. When a user clicks a button, I am trying to edit the embed to show something else. But then I get a

> TypeError: interaction.message.edit() is not a function.

I can print out the `interaction.message` and it shows the message Object, but the function can not be called. I am using the `interactionCreate` event.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `interaction.update()` method:

```
// send a message

message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed], components: [buttons] })

/*
listen for the "interactionCreate" event or use any other method
of detecting an interaction like interaction collectors or awaitMessageComponent 
*/

client.on("interactionCreate", (interaction) => {
    interaction.update({ embeds: [aDifferentEmbed] })
})
```